# Euler 22/Sorting Names in Alphabetical Order

Tags: c, string, sorting, copy

I've been trying to sort these names from the Euler #22 problem. I tried many ways to swap strings. I had problem every time. In some, there were random symbols; in others i had overflowed(?) names while swapping(Like ending up with LINDACIA while trying to swap PATRICIA and LINDA). I tried to add a symbol each free byte in string (like LINDAzzzzzzzzz\0) and got compiler error.

#### Input File

```
"MARY","PATRICIA","LINDA","BARBARA","ELIZABETH","JENNIFER","MARIA","SUSAN","MARGARET"
```

#### Source Code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *nameorder;
    char liste[5164][15];
    char hold[15];
    int i=0,j=0,k;
    int c;
    FILE *ptr;
    nameorder ="names.txt";
    ptr= fopen( nameorder , "r");
    if(ptr==0)
    {
        printf("File could not be opened");
        return 0;
    }
    while( (c=getc(ptr)) != EOF) //reading character by character
    {
        if(c=='"')
        {
            continue;
        }
        if(c==',')
        {
            j=0;
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        liste[i][j]=c;
        j++;
    }
    fclose(ptr);
    for(k=0;k<5163;k++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<5164;i++) //
        {
            if( strcmp(liste[i],liste[i+1])>0 )
            {
                strncpy(hold,liste[i],15);
                strncpy(liste[i],liste[i+1],15);
                strncpy(liste[i+1],hold,15);
            }
            else
                continue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: it's better to use if(ptr) instead of if(ptr == 0)

Comment: @ThisaruGuruge: It's not better when you invert the conditional. `if (ptr == 0)` is the same as `if (!ptr)`.

Comment: Oh a typo..... i mean if(!ptr) :) @sharth

Comment: @user3121023 Thanks! That solved it. I didn't think it was this easy. Null is too strong. 
I'll keep that in mind too, Thisaru!

Comment: The best way to sort strings is to create an array of pointers, one pointer to each string, them manipulate that array of pointers rather than trying to move the actual strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very least, you don't null terminate your strings. This will matter for all of the names that are not exactly 15 characters long.

The easiest way to fix this is to initialize your entire array to zero.

```
char liste[5164][15] = {{0}};
```